# Инициализировать new File() существующий файлом java.io.File

Tags: java

У меня есть на компе файл index.html
как мне получить его в файл чтобы потом начать с ним работать?

делаю

```
String link = classPage.getFullFilePATH(); // в дебаге возвращает путь c:\\...
File file = new File(link);
```

в итоге создается файл равным переданный ссылке а не сам index.html, а мне нужно ее саму открыть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно считывать данные из файла на компьютере вот так:

```
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(C:\\abc.abc); // объект fr для считывания файла
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fr); // построчное чтение файла сканнером
```

И закрыть поток не забудьте:

```
fr.close(); // закрывается поток чтения файла
```

Comment: Я сделал себе программу для считывания исходного файла с компьютера, построчной обработки данных из считанного файла и сохранения обработанной информации в новый файл на компьютере.

Comment: Чтобы не забывать закрывать поток, надо юзать `try with resources`

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вот просидел и промучился над вашим вопросом несколько минут.Конструктор класса File перегруженный:

```
File(String путь_к_каталогу)
File(String путь_к_каталогу, String имя_файла)
File(File каталог, String имя_файла)
```

Используйте любой из этих конструкторов для того,чтобы связать объект класса File с файлом на жестком диске.

```
try{
File file = new File("E:\\Lab Web-design\\WEB\\lab1 - Web" , "task1.html");// 
связываем переменную с файлом.
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);//Создаем символьный поток
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);//Создаем буфер
String line = null;
   while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null){//Читаем построчно
     //here is you code...
}catch(IOException ex){
   //...
}catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
   //...
      }
   }
}
```